# Binding multiple view models on single tag

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following select tag:

```
<select data-bind="value: schedule_id, options: courses, optionsText: 'title', optionsValue: 'schedule_id'"></select>
```

I have 2 view models. One manages courses and the other manages reviews.

The problem I'm facing is that the `select` needs to get its values from the courseViewModel and my reviewViewModel needs to observe what value is selected so it knows what course is being reviewed.

So I need to bind `options: courses, optionsText: 'title', optionsValue: 'schedule_id'` to my courseViewModel and bind `value: schedule_id` to my reviewViewModel so it knows what course was selected to review.

When I apply the bindings for the courseViewModel, I get an error saying no binding exists for `value: schedule_id`.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You solve that by defining a proper view model.

The idea in a view model is that it contains all the data required by the view to generate the representation of that data.

You can:

1. Combine both view models
2. Define a 3rd view model that has the relevant data parts
3. As an "advanced" technique, you could generate a property(s) on one of the models that actually access values from the 2nd model. use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to define a getter for values that don't "exist" in the view model itself, but a rather pulled from the other view model.